# Visualizing Data in 3 Dimensions

Tags: data-visualization

I want a way to visualize this table as a graph: there is one categorical variable, and 4 quantitative variables. Each of the 20 values in the table would also vary with time (lets say it's annual data and there are 5 time points).

Is there a nice way to plot the data that would incorporate all of these aspects of the data?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you could provide some example data for people to work with. Do you just want to see how the quantitative variables are related? Do you want to see differences in distributions / relationships by category? Are the categories a response such that you want to see how the proportions change as a function of the variables? You mention time, which isn't represented here; do you want to see if something (what) changes over time?

Comment: No, the quantitative variables aren't related to each other. I would like to compare trends for each quantitative variable over time, where the trend would be broken down by the categorical variable. The categorical variable in my data set is Canadian province, and the quantitative variables are financial ratios

Comment: I would suggest using not just one plot, but several. As @gung said, providing some data (and you can make it unrecognizable easily) helps a lot. That being said, boxplots for every categorical variable side-by-side would probably convey part of the information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some toy data and code that works. I decided to make separate plots for each quantitative variable, and within each plot, lines of different colors are used to show how the quantitative variable changes across the 5 time points for each of the categories.

```
# Generate data
set.seed(23)
c <- rep(c("c1","c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), 5)
q1 <- runif(25)
q2 <- runif(25)
q3 <- runif(25)
q4 <- runif(25)
df <- data.frame(c, q1, q2, q3, q4)

# Plot
layout(matrix(1:4,2,2, byrow=T))
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(min(df[,2:5]), max(df[,2:5])), ylab="", xlab="", main="q1")
lines(df[df$c=="c1","q1"]~c(1:5), col="black")
lines(df[df$c=="c2","q1"]~c(1:5), col="blue")
lines(df[df$c=="c3","q1"]~c(1:5), col="green")
lines(df[df$c=="c4","q1"]~c(1:5), col="red")
lines(df[df$c=="c5","q1"]~c(1:5), col="purple")
legend(0.5,1.5, legend=c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"), col=c("black", "blue", "green", "red", "purple"), lty=1, cex=0.5, xpd=TRUE)
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(min(df[,2:5]), max(df[,2:5])), ylab="", xlab="", main="q2")
lines(df[df$c=="c1","q3"]~c(1:5), col="black")
lines(df[df$c=="c2","q3"]~c(1:5), col="blue")
lines(df[df$c=="c3","q3"]~c(1:5), col="green")
lines(df[df$c=="c4","q3"]~c(1:5), col="red")
lines(df[df$c=="c5","q3"]~c(1:5), col="purple")
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(min(df[,2:5]), max(df[,2:5])), ylab="", xlab="", main="q3")
lines(df[df$c=="c1","q2"]~c(1:5), col="black")
lines(df[df$c=="c2","q2"]~c(1:5), col="blue")
lines(df[df$c=="c3","q2"]~c(1:5), col="green")
lines(df[df$c=="c4","q2"]~c(1:5), col="red")
lines(df[df$c=="c5","q2"]~c(1:5), col="purple")
plot(1, 1, type="n", xlim=c(1,5), ylim=c(min(df[,2:5]), max(df[,2:5])), ylab="", xlab="", main="q4")
lines(df[df$c=="c1","q1"]~c(1:5), col="black")
lines(df[df$c=="c2","q1"]~c(1:5), col="blue")
lines(df[df$c=="c3","q1"]~c(1:5), col="green")
lines(df[df$c=="c4","q1"]~c(1:5), col="red")
lines(df[df$c=="c5","q1"]~c(1:5), col="purple")
```

[image]

The exact code will depend on how your data is structured, and a lot could be done to improve the aesthetics, but in general this sort of layout could represent your data well.